# Spring MVC 4 - Tiles3 - Tiles-extras dependency crashes applicaiton

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have an application up and working using Spring Boot (Maven).  Currently configured as WAR with Stand Alone Tomcat.  Everything works fine.

If I add `tiles-extras` v3.0.5 the application will crash with the following error.  I am not using FreeMarker in the application.  JSP & Tiles Only.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find template location(s): [classpath:/templates/] (please add some templates, check your FreeMarker configuration, or set spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation=false)
```

**EDIT** Adding viewResolver incase it is needed.

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
    viewResolver.setOrder(0);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

**Change Implemented**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>${tiles.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-freemarker</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-velocity</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
                <artifactId>tiles-request-mustache</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

**New Error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory
```

Comment: Exclude Freemarker as a dependency for `tiles-extra`. The free marker dependency triggers the registration of some Freemarker components in Spring Boot.

Comment: Another tips instead of using a `UrlBasedViewResolver` use the `TilesViewResolver`, saves you a couple of lines of code.

Comment: Your first comment was dead on.  That solved the problem with Spring Boot.  And you are right it does save a line :-) I still need the setOrder though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

When adding `tiles-extras` as a dependency this automatically adds a lot of other `tiles-*` dependencies, see the [pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tiles/tiles-extras/3.0.5/tiles-extras-3.0.5.pom). You might either want to exclude `freemarker` or the `tiles-freemarker` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-freemarker</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If you aren't using template engines you also might want to exclude the `velocity` dependency.

Comment: I did try it just excluding freemaker, still get this new error.

Comment: You migh need to add the `asp-api` as a dependency (could be that it normally is a transitive dependency of one of the jars you are excluding). Do you get it when deployed or running as standalone jar/war?

Comment: The error comes from running under a war with Maven set as Tomcat provided.  The funny part is that I did figure out how to accomplish what I needed without the need for tiles-extra.

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as the answer, could be specific to my build and using Spring Boot.